# Looking for list of email tokens for WSO2 notification mail

Tags: wso2

I am trying to set up the account recovery with notification.
Is there any place, where  i could get the list of all available tokens for use in notification email templates?
i am specifically looking for tokens that identify the tenant/domain for a user.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the email-­admin-­config.xml file with the following configuration under {carbon_home}/repository/conf/email. AFAIK there are no additional token options.